# Get all cryptographic algorithms per provider and service

Tags: android, security, kotlin, cryptography

My name is Panagiotis and I want to share with you my solution about a problem I faced.

**My Problem:**

Recently I created an android library for my application having implemented some standard functionality about cryptography. My major question was what kind of transformations I could use to encrypt and decrypt my data. My first step was to seek information on internet but I didn't find something that was suitable for me. I wanted a list with all correct names of the transformations.

Below you will see my solution!

Panagiotis Vangelatos

Answer (score 1):

**My solution in Kotlin:**

To begin with, I have created the "AlgorithmsPerProviderAndService" class that contains the service name and all the available algorithms per provider.

```
private class AlgorithmsPerProviderAndService constructor(private val serviceName: String)
{
    private val ServiceName:  String      get() = serviceName
    val ProviderName: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> = HashMap()
}
```

I created the below part of code to get all the available algorithms per services and providers that are used by android.

```
    // StringBuilder object to display the data
    val sb  = StringBuilder()

    // "Info" HashMap that will has as key the name of the service and as value my custom class
    // that will hold the algorithm's names per provider
    val info: HashMap<String, AlgorithmsPerProviderAndService> = HashMap()

    // Part of code that reads all the available providers and for each provider get the 
    // corresponding services and the algorithm's names
    Security.getProviders().toList().sortedBy { it.name }.forEach {
        it.services.sortedBy { it1 -> it1.type }.forEach {it1 ->
            // Check if the "info" HashMap is empty and if is empty then add the first service
            // and the corresponding FIRST provider and FIRST algorithm
            if (info.size == 0)
            {
                val currentData = AlgorithmsPerProviderAndService(it1.type)
                currentData.ProviderName.put(it.name, arrayListOf(it1.algorithm))
                info.put(it1.type, currentData)
            }
            // If the "info" HashMap is not empty, then check if the current service already exists.
            // The reason that I check if the current services exists is because I want to have 
            // each service only one time into the "info" HashMap
            else
            {
                // Because the current service may have been implemented by more than one provider
                // and because I want to have the all algorithms that have been implemented by all 
                // provides, in case of the current service already exists, I check if the current
                // provider exists or not.
                if (info.containsKey(it1.type))
                {
                    // If the provider exists, I want to add only the available algorithms for the 
                    // current provider 
                    if (info[it1.type]!!.ProviderName.containsKey(it.name))
                    {
                        info[it1.type]!!.ProviderName[it.name]!!.add(it1.algorithm)
                    }
                    // If the provider does not exist, then I want to add both the new provider and 
                    // only the FIRST algorithm (because the other algorithms will be add when the 
                    // above condition is true)
                    else
                    {
                        info[it1.type]!!.ProviderName.put(it.name, arrayListOf(it1.algorithm))
                    }
                }
                // If this case, the current service does not exists, so adding it and in addition
                // I am adding provider (of the current service) and only the first algorithm.
                else
                {
                    val currentData = AlgorithmsPerProviderAndService(it1.type)
                    currentData.ProviderName.put(it.name, arrayListOf(it1.algorithm))
                    info.put(it1.type, currentData)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Display data
    info.toSortedMap().forEach {
        sb.appendln("Service: " + it.key)

        it.value.ProviderName.toSortedMap().forEach {it1 ->
            sb.appendln("\tProvider: " + it1.key)

            it1.value.sort()
            it1.value.forEach {it2 ->
                sb.appendln("\t\tAlgorithm: $it2")
            }

            sb.appendln()
        }

        sb.appendln()
    }
```

I hope to have written understandable comments! If someone wants to discuss the code will be my pleasant and I am waiting your comments and optimizations!

Vangelatos Panagiotis